# Windows desktop mic loud on skype but quiet on gotomeeting

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, audio, microphone

I have a low-end CA desktop PC mic that sounds loud and clear (to the people on the other end) on Skype, but very quiet to the others on GoToMeeting. I have gone into Control Panel mic settings and the volume is already all the way up. I can't find any mic volume settings inside GTM, so there seems to be no way to turn up my mic volume within the perspective of that app.

I really think that the OS or mic software or GoToMeeting is assuming that the audio input is coming from a headset in which mouth is half-inch from mic, rather than a desktop mic in which mouth can be 6-12 inches from mic. Yet Skype obviously expects/allows desktop mic, and thus picks up sound from further away from the mic. How can I get GTM to do the same thing?

What can I do?

Comment: Each application should have it's own Audio settings.  For example, on my work laptop, I have a tuning wizard for: Cisco IP Phone.  And you can set the levels for that application.  Go to Meeting I know has it's own settings and Skype should too.

Answer (score 0):

I called Citrix/GTM support and got this problem solved.

Solution:

1. In the Audio tab, click Sound Check
2. Click the Mic icon tab
3. Click the gear icon for advanced settings
4. At the bottom (Advanced area) there are 2 checkboxes: "Automatically adjust my system mixer settings" and "Use automatic volume and noise processing" -- UNCHECK both
5. The problem should now be solved